# How to read multiple items in ItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

Following is my use case for spring batch.

1. Reads the input from web service.  Web service will return all records.
2. Process the records.
3. Write the processed records one by one.

I'm clear about step 2 and 3 but not able to figure out how to implement a reader which can read all the records in one go. How to pass the records one by one to item processor /writer? 
Should I be using  tasklet instead of reader/writer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What will your WebService Returns?  A collection of object i guess!

Your ItemReader need to loop on this collection and remove items one-by-one then return null when they are all processed.

What @Kik was saying is the rest is handled by Spring batch based on your commit-interval.  if you have a commit0interval of 10 for example, your reader will read 10 items, passed those 10 items to the ItemProc. then pass them again after to the writer.

Hope it clarify

EDIT:  1) In Spring Batch you have more than one option to do what you need.

Easy Option, create a custom MyWsItemReader that implements the ItemReader interface.

-Define a method init() in this class that will call your webService and put the results in a collection attribute of MyWsItemReader.

-Implements the method read() from the interface. (read carfully the contact in the doc - you must return null when you passed all the elements of the collection)

-Then, configure a stepListener around the step and implement the beforeStep() method to call the init() of your MyWsItemReader.  You can autowire the reader in the listener to accomplish this.

Alternatively, your MyWsItemReader could also implements the InitializingBean.  then you would have to implement the afterPropertySet() where you could call the ws and store the result in a private attribute of MyWsItemReader

regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i didnt get it. I'm not too deep in spring batch.  My understanding is that reader is called multiple times and prepare the list of object and it is passed to processor/writer. So my questions...

Comment: Sorry i couldn't write the whole comment. Thanks for the answer. But i didn’t get it. I'm not too deep in spring batch.  My understanding is that reader is called multiple times and prepares the list of object and it is passed to processor/writer. So my questions
1.Where should I make a call to web service?  And even if I make it in reader, how to pass that list to writer and processer? Any sample would be great help... 
2.Should I use tasklet to call make web service call? If yes, how should I pass my items to reader and writer? If I use the tasklet my job will consists two steps.

Comment: see edit.  First, the readers must be initialized with a collection of objects (mapped from a Jdbc call, an Xml, a flatFile..etc). This is done ONCE.  Then the read() method is called by chunk define by the commit-interval in your chunk config. Every chunk will be read, then passed to ItemProcessor,ItemWriter AUTOMATICALLY by Spring Batch.... you have nothing to code for this, it is all in the step configuration.

Comment: thanks that worked. I saw spring batch reader code. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Instead of calling the init() in beforeStep() or afterPropertySet(), why not implement ItemStream and call init() during open() which is more appropriate and it also properly supports restartability.

Comment: @Ken Very good point, i was using open to manage executionContext State... but as you mention... you could initialize your reader collection there

Comment: @KenstonChoi But the open() method is gettig called during every step though. Can you provide an example ?

Comment: @PavanSandeep open() is expected to be called once for every new step similar to the beforeStep() being called before starting every new step.